# How do I deduce all of a person's descendants?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, protege

Here is my example.owl:

```
@prefix : <#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://ex.org> .

<http://ex.org> rdf:type owl:Ontology .
:hasChild rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
          rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasDescendant .
:hasDaughter rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
             rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasChild ;
             owl:propertyDisjointWith :hasSon .
:hasDescendant rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .
:hasSon rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
            rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasChild .
:Person rdf:type owl:Class .

:Bob rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Person ;
              :hasDaughter :Mary ;
              :hasSon :John .
:LittleBoy rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Person .
:LittleGirl rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,  :Person .
:John rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,  :Person ;
      :hasSon :LittleBoy .
:Mary rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Person ;
      :hasDaughter :LittleGirl .
```

I want to get all of a Bob's descendants or  Bob's child by a Sparql query,
How do I write this SPARQL statement?
Thanks for help.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: `select distinct ?child {:Bob (:hasDaughter|:hasSon)+ ?child}`

Comment: Thank you, UninformedUser. I'm sorry I didn't state the question clearly enough, I'm asking if there's a generic query statement that can do this when the subProperty  of  hasDescendant might increase dynamically ,such as hasGodSon, hasAdoptedSon, etc.

Comment: not possibel with standard SPARQL 1.1 without entailment because you can't use variables in property paths. So while you could indeed get all relevant properties via `select ?p {?p rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasDescendant}` you cannot use those ?p in a property path like you would need, i.e. it is impossible to do `select distinct ?child {?p rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasDescendant . :Bob (?p)+ ?child }`

Comment: And yes, there is a workaround for the property path limitation, but in general this doesn't scale for deep graphs: `prefix : <http://ex.org#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?child {
?p rdfs:subPropertyOf* :hasDescendant .
:Bob (<p>|!<p>)* ?mid . ?mid (<p>|!<p>)+ ?child
FILTER EXISTS {?mid ?p ?child}
}`

Comment: Thanks. But the above code does not return any value.

Comment: it does for sure, change the prefix declaration in your data from `@prefix : <#> .` to `@prefix : <http://ex.org#> .`

Comment: Yes, it was very careless of me. This is the first time I've seen sparql used like this. It's amazing. Thank you UniformedUser.

Comment: @UninformedUser, I agree with the first comment that it doesn't seem possible. The workaround doesn't seem to work in all cases. For example, with `:Bob :knows :Alice . :Alice :knows :Carol . :Carol :hasDescendant :Dave .`, we would get `:Dave` as a result. I don't think this is possible at all in SPARQL 1.1.